# Why isn't my tag listed when I checkout with Git GUI?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-gui

I have a local Git repository with three annotated tags: `v0.1.0`, `v0.1.1`, and `v0.1.2`.

When I view my project's history with `gitk` (*Repository → Visualize master's history*), I can see each tag assigned to the proper commit.

[image: Project history in gitk]

However, when I try to checkout my tags in Git GUI (*Branch → Checkout... → Tags*), the tag for `v0.1.1` doesn't appear.

[image: Git GUI tag list]

When I went to check each tag in gitk, I noticed that the details for `v0.1.0` and `v0.1.2` listed them as `type commit`, while the tag for `v0.1.1` was listed as `type tag`.

[image: Details for tag v0.1.1]

It's worth noting that I've rewritten history on this tag to fix a typo. I edited my tag message using [`git tag <tag name> <tag name> -f -m "<new message>"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813236/3357935).

**Why can't I see my `v0.1.1` tag when checking out with Git GUI? Why does it appear as `type tag`?**

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43859023/211627 Sounds like maybe v0.1.1 was accidentally created to point to another tag.

Comment: What do you get if you type `git show ca5728b` into the command line? Does it show you a commit, a tag, or something else?

Comment: @JDB That's likely the cause. I used [`git tag <oldtag> <newtag>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/3357935) to rename an older tag.

Comment: Yeah... sounds like you tagged the tag rather than the commit.

Comment: Yeah... that answer is probably not a good idea. I mean, `git checkout` will still probably be able to figure it out, but [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) states pretty clearly that the second argument is the thing you are tagging. If you use `git tag new old` then your new tag is actually pointing to the old tag, *not* the old tag's commit.

Comment: I am investigating further... there's a difference here between annotated tags and lightweight tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166844/discussion-between-steven-vascellaro-and-jdb).

Comment: Related: [How to rename an annotated tag in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34012095/3357935)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tags can [point to any object](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#git-tag-ltobjectgt) in the git repository. If your tag type is "tag", then you have a tag pointing to another tag.

**Lightweight tags *are not* objects**; thus, they have no hash ID of their own and nothing else (like another tag) can point to them. They are literally just easy-to-remember names pointing to some object's hash ID, a little less than a branch name.

However, **annotated tags *are* objects**; they are like commits, with their own message, author, created date and, most importantly, their own hash ID. This means that, somewhat confusingly, they can be tagged.

Sure enough, as you described in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283734/why-cant-i-checkout-my-tag-from-git-gui#comment85570763_49283734), this is exactly what happened. Acting on the advice found in [How do you rename a Git tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/3357935), you did the following:

```
# avoid this...
git tag new old
```

Since `old` was an annotated tag, the target for the `new` tag will be the `old` tag, not the commit that it was pointing to.

If you want to rename an annotated tag, you should use

```
git tag -a new old^{}
```

`old^{}` will [*dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrevgtemegemv0998em) (in our case, a commit), and use that as the target object for `new`.

---

To further illustrate: let's say you have a repo... oh, like this one: https://github.com/cyborgx37/sandbox/releases

In this repo you create an annotated tag like so:

```
> git tag -m "Version 0.1-beat" v0.1
```

Oh shoot... you misspelled "beta" and also you've decided that you want the tag name to be `v0.1-b`. Since this has already been published, you decide to do the [sane thing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_re_tagging) and just create a new tag. Following [advice you found on the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/3357935), you create the tag you actually wanted (I appended `__tag` for reasons that will become clear) by copying the first tag:

```
> git tag -m "Version 0.1-beta" v0.1-b__tag v0.1
```

Only, these are annotated tags, meaning they are actual objects. So when you created `v0.1-b__tag`, you actually pointed it at `v0.1`. You can see the result clearly using `cat-file` and `show`.

Here's **`v0.1`**:

```bash
> git cat-file -p v0.1

object 5cf4de319291579d4416da8e0eba8a2973f8b0cf
type commit # ⇦ v0.1 is a tag which points to a commit
tag v0.1
tagger JDB <jd@domain.com> 1521058797 -0400
    
Version 0.1-beat
```

```bash
> git show v0.1

# v0.1 is a tag
# ⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩

tag v0.1
Tagger: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 16:19:57 2018 -0400

Version 0.1-beat

# which is pointing directly to a commit
# ⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩

commit 5cf4de319291579d4416da8e0eba8a2973f8b0cf (HEAD -> master, tag: v0.1-b__tag, tag: v0.1, origin/master)
Author: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 10 12:17:00 2017 -0400

    add gitignore

diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..42d9955
--- /dev/null
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+file.txt
```

Notice that **`v0.1-b__tag`** is different both in its target type as well as its history:

```bash
> git cat-file -p v0.1-b__tag

object 889b82584b2294486f4956dfea17b05e6224fb7f
type tag # ⇦ v0.1-b__tag is a tag which points to a tag
tag v0.1-b__tag
tagger JDB <jd@domain.com> 1521059058 -0400

Version 0.1-beta
```

```bash
> git show v0.1-b__tag

# v0.1-b__tag is a tag
# ⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩

tag v0.1-b__tag
Tagger: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 16:24:18 2018 -0400

Version 0.1-beta

# which is pointing to the v0.1 tag
# ⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩

tag v0.1
Tagger: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 16:19:57 2018 -0400

Version 0.1-beat

# which is pointing to the intended target commit
# ⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩⇩

commit 5cf4de319291579d4416da8e0eba8a2973f8b0cf (HEAD -> master, tag: v0.1-b__tag, tag: v0.1, origin/master)
Author: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 10 12:17:00 2017 -0400

    add gitignore

diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..42d9955
--- /dev/null
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+file.txt
```

Apparently Git GUI is rather selective about what types of objects can be checked out (commits, not tags), so it's ignoring your tag pointing at another tag.

If you use the `git tag -a new old^{}` approach I suggested above, you can avoid the drama and get what you wanted in the first place. I'll create a new tag, **`v0.1-b__commit`** that points to `v0.1`'s commit, rather than to `v0.1` directly:

```
> git tag -m "Version 0.1-beta" v0.1-b__commit v0.1^{}
```

```
> git cat-file -p v0.1-b__commit

object 5cf4de319291579d4416da8e0eba8a2973f8b0cf
type commit
tag v0.1-b__commit
tagger JDB <jd@domain.com> 1521059039 -0400

Version 0.1-beta
```

```
> git show v0.1-b__commit

tag v0.1-b__commit
Tagger: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 14 16:23:59 2018 -0400

Version 0.1-beta

commit 5cf4de319291579d4416da8e0eba8a2973f8b0cf (HEAD -> master, tag: v0.1-b__tag, tag: v0.1-b__commit, tag: v0.1, origin/master)
Author: JDB <jd@domain.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 10 12:17:00 2017 -0400

    add gitignore

diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..42d9955
--- /dev/null
+++ b/.gitignore
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+file.txt
```

Comment: Can I edit my current tag to point to the commit? Or is it easier to delete and re-add a new tag?

Comment: It depends if other developers are using your tag. You can modify it and force push it, but this could cause issues if other developers are using it.

Comment: This is a locally-saved private repository that has never been used by any other developers.

Comment: Then, following the advice in that article, you are perfectly safe to re-tag away.

Comment: Updated to include more detail and an example

Comment: Will `git tag -a new old^{}` preserve the old tag's date?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It won't do anything to the old tag. The new tag will get it's own date regardless of which approach you take, but you can [backdate tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_backdating_tags) if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't normally use any of the Git GUIs so the GUI-specific parts, I can't really answer—but your observation that there's a difference here between *annotated tags* and *lightweight tags* is spot-on, and yes, there should be some warning(s) in some of the answers to [How do you rename a Git tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/1256452)

> When I went to check each tag in gitk, I noticed that the tag details were slightly different. The details for `v0.1.0` and `v0.1.2` listed them as `type commit`, while the tag for `v0.1.1` was listed as type tag. I suspect this may be the cause of my problem ...

Let's clear up the difference between these, and talk about the mechanisms behind tags.

In Git, the "true name" of any actual commit is the commit's hash ID.  Hash IDs are long, ugly, impossible-to-remember strings, such as the `ca5728b6...` showing in one of your GUI panes.  I made a new, empty repository and made one commit in it:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo for testing tags > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) a912caa] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git rev-parse HEAD
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
```

This identifies a commit, and we can see that using `git cat-file -t`, which tells us about the *type* of each internal Git object:

```
$ git cat-file -t a912c
commit
```

You can abbreviate the big ugly IDs as long as the abbreviation is unique and is at least four letters.<sup>1</sup>

Anyway, now let's make two different tags, pointing to this same commit:

```
$ git tag -m "an annotated tag" annotag
$ git tag lightweight
```

and use `git for-each-ref` to inspect them:

```
$ git for-each-ref
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572 commit refs/heads/master
dc4695ffede0a877fdc61dc06f5ad5c6d5cfc356 tag    refs/tags/annotag
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572 commit refs/tags/lightweight
```

The annotated tag has a different hash ID than the lightweight tag.

The trick here is that the lightweight tag creates *only* a name in the reference database, in this case, `refs/tags/lightweight`.  Names in the reference database store hash IDs, so this one stores the hash ID of our single commit.

An annotated tag, on the other hand, exists as an actual repository object, so we can inspect its type and see its contents, using `git cat-file`:

```
$ git cat-file -t dc4695ffede0a877fdc61dc06f5ad5c6d5cfc356
tag
$ git cat-file -p dc4695ffede0a877fdc61dc06f5ad5c6d5cfc356 | sed 's/@/ /'
object a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
type commit
tag annotag
tagger Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1521059496 -0700

an annotated tag
```

Note that the annotated tag object, in the *repository* database keyed by hash ID and containing object data, contains the hash ID of the commit.  There is, in effect, also a "lightweight-like" tag named `refs/tags/annotag` pointing to the annotated tag object.  But since it points to an annotated tag object, it's treated as an annotated tag.

When you make a new tag, you can point it to any existing object.  Let's take a look at the objects associated with the single commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 4d73be7092200632865da23347ba0af4ac6c91f7
author Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1521053169 -0700
committer Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1521053169 -0700

initial
```

This commit object refers to a tree object, which we can inspect:

```
$ git cat-file -p 4d73be7092200632865da23347ba0af4ac6c91f7
100644 blob 938c7cff87a9b753ae70d91412d3ead5c95ef932    README
```

and the tree points to a *blob* object, which we can also inspect:

```
$ git cat-file -p 938c7cff87a9b753ae70d91412d3ead5c95ef932
for testing tags
```

which is the content of the file `README`.  Let's tag that:

```
$ git tag the-file 938c7cff87a9b753ae70d91412d3ead5c95ef932
```

and inspect its type:

```
$ git cat-file -t the-file
blob
```

This is not the normal use of a tag, but it's allowed.  Let's try making a lightweight tag for the annotated tag:

```
$ git tag maybe-light annotag
$ git cat-file -t maybe-light
tag
$ git cat-file -p maybe-light | sed 's/@/ /'
object a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
type commit
tag annotag
tagger Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1521059496 -0700

an annotated tag
```

This `maybe-light` tag points to the annotated tag *object* that belongs to the annotated tag `annotag`.  Is `maybe-light` an *annotated tag*?  That depends on your point of view, doesn't it?  I would say that it both is and isn't: it's a lightweight tag pointing to an annotated tag, but it's not *the* lightweight tag that goes by the same name as the annotated tag object, which claims right inside the object to be / belong-to `annotag`.  But I would also say that in a way, `annotag` is both a lightweight and annotated tag: it's a lightweight tag that gives the ID of the annotated tag object.  They use the same name so I'd call it an "annotated tag" and refer to `refs/tags/annotag` as the tag name, the same way `refs/tags/maybe-light` is a tag name.

In any case, we can also make more annotated tags pointing to any of these objects.  If we make an annotated tag pointing to the other annotated tag, we end up with two annotated tag objects in the repository:

```
$ git tag -m "also annotated" anno2
$ git for-each-ref
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572 commit refs/heads/master
060527046d210f0219170cdc6354afe4834ddc6d tag    refs/tags/anno2
dc4695ffede0a877fdc61dc06f5ad5c6d5cfc356 tag    refs/tags/annotag
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572 commit refs/tags/lightweight
dc4695ffede0a877fdc61dc06f5ad5c6d5cfc356 tag    refs/tags/maybe-light
938c7cff87a9b753ae70d91412d3ead5c95ef932 blob   refs/tags/the-file
```

You can see from this that `anno2` has a new object, `0605...`:

```
$ git cat-file -p 0605 | sed 's/@/ /'
object a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
type commit
tag anno2
tagger Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1521060518 -0700

also annotated
```

Meanwhile, `git for-each-ref` describes the `maybe-light` tag as a `tag` rather than a `commit`: that just tells us that its immediate target object, without following through to further objects, is a tag, not a commit.

Let's make one more annotated tag, for the blob:

```
$ git tag -m "annotated blob" annoblob the-file
```

Since it's an annotated tag, `git for-each-ref` says that its type is `tag` (try it!).

Git calls the process of following a tag to its ultimate object "peeling the tag", and there is a special syntax for that:

```
$ git rev-parse annotag annotag^{} annoblob annoblob^{}
dc4695ffede0a877fdc61dc06f5ad5c6d5cfc356
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
398b3b89e0377b8942e2f84c97a24afaad0dccb0
938c7cff87a9b753ae70d91412d3ead5c95ef932
```

Note that this is different from just following the tag *once*, as we see if we parse `anno2` this way:

```
$ git rev-parse anno2^{}
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
```

The `a912...` is the ID of the commit, not the second annotated tag.  Compare with:

```
$ git rev-parse anno2 anno2^{tag}
060527046d210f0219170cdc6354afe4834ddc6d
060527046d210f0219170cdc6354afe4834ddc6d
```

The first finds the ID of the object to which `anno2` points; the second verifies that it's a database object of type `tag`.  Both are of course the same ID, and it is indeed an object of type `tag`.  We can ask specifically for a commit:

```
$ git rev-parse anno2^{commit}
a912caa83de69ef8e5e3e06c3d74b6c409068572
```

but if we do this with the name `annoblob` we get an error:

```
$ git rev-parse annoblob^{commit}
error: annoblob^{commit}: expected commit type, but the object
 dereferences to blob type
```

which is why the `^{}` syntax exists: it means *follow tags until you reach a non-tag, whatever that is.*

---

<sup>1</sup>The four-character limit means that if you name a branch `cab`, you're OK.  If you name it `face`, though, is that a *branch name* or a *raw hash ID*?  What if it could be more than one thing?  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for hints, but the answer is: *it depends on the command*. If you spell out the reference, `refs/heads/face` or even just `heads/face`, it no longer resembles both a branch name *and* an abbreviated hash ID.  Unfortunately `git checkout` demands the unadorned name `face` (but always treats it as a branch name, if it can).

---

#### Summary

A *tag name* is simply a name in the `refs/tags/` name-space.  The `git tag` command can make new tag names.  This name must point to some hash ID; the ID can be the ID of any existing object, or you can have `git tag` make a new tag object.

A *tag object* or *annotated tag object* is an entity in the repository database.  It has a unique hash ID, just like a commit.  It has type `tag` (vs a commit, which has type `commit`).  Its metadata consists of the *target object*, the tagger name, the tag name, any message you like, and an optional PGP signature.

The *target object* of a tag object is any existing object in the repository database.  That object needs to exist when creating the tag object.  This prevents the annotated tag from pointing to itself, or to a tag object you have not yet created, which prevents cycles in the graph.

Running `git tag` to make a new tag creates either just the tag name pointing to some existing object, or the tag name pointing to a new tag object pointing to some existing object.  The existing object, whatever it is, continues existing.

Running `git tag -d` deletes *only the tag name*.  The tag *object*, if there is one, remains in the repository.  Like commit objects, it will eventually be garbage-collected and discarded if and only if there are no other references by which one can reach the tag object.  (This happens some time in the future, when `git gc` runs.)